# Why people don't harvest Locusts when infestation happeds?

Tags: entomology, agriculture

We've heard about tremendous amount of money losses even leading to famine due to crop destruction from locust infestation over and over again, but all these grasshoppers are a valuable protein, probably way more valuable than the destroyed crops. Although most people from many cultures won't eat such insects, these can be ground to flour and stored to be fed to omnivore livestock like pigs or sold for profit or exchanged for grains.

Is there edible energy in the insect swarms? Can this be made into livestock feed? If not, is the reason this isn't common practice biological or economical?

Comment: The problem, Nigel, is that crops can be stored for months, whereas locusts are a mostly perishable food.

Comment: I don't think so. Dry proteins for commercial use can be stored for quite some time. Also after some research, it turns out that Meat and bone meal (MBM) has a shelf life of 12 months. Furthermore, there is a ton of consumable insects sold online vacuum-packed and cooked. And to top all this we live in a global economy where it won't matter anyway.

Comment: You have made my point for me. What you propose is much costlier than harvesting wheat, which needs very little by way of processing after harvesting. :) A global economy might not be an inconvenience to you, but to the farmers whose crops are consumed by locusts, I imagine they could hardly care less about global economies.

Answer (score 2):

Locusts have been harvested in Thailand and Australia they call them sky-prawns. They deep-fry them and consume them happily.

http://www.bugsfeed.com/locust

http://www.fao.org/docrep/017/i3246e/i3246e.pdf

In Thailand Orthoptera or
grasshoppers include Patanga succincta,
Locusta migratoria, Acrida sp.,
Cyrtacanthacris tatarica and Oxya
japonica japonica (Thunb.)
(Hanboonsong et al. 2001; RaƩ anapan
2000). All of them are pests of
economic crops such as maize and
rice. Grasshopper species, parƟ cularly
Patanga succincta and Locusta
migratoria, used to be one of the
major pests of maize and rice. Today
they have become one of the most
popular edible insects since they were
introduced for human consumpƟ on
by entomologists − a campaign to eat
grasshoppers had been launched
because control efforts had been
unsuccessful. For example, in 1983
this was launched by local offi cials and
villagers in Prachin Buri Province
collected more than 10 tonnes for use
as food (Lewvanich et al. 1999).*